# how do I password protect all pages except login page in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have created a asp.net core 6 mvc web application. I did not add user authorization from start but added ASP.NET Core Identity afterwards instead. My question is how do I make all pages password protected except the actual login page that the users shoud be redirected to if they havent logged in yet? Is that something I configure in program.cs or how do i do that?

here is my **program.cs** file...

```
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Password settings.
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

            // Lockout settings.
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

            // User settings.
            options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
                "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
        });

        
        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

        
        var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDb");
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

         
        builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();


        var app = builder.Build();


        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }



        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseAuthenticationCheck();

        //app.UseAuthentication();

        app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        app.Run();
```

Update I added this middleware to check if user is authenticated, if not he need to login on the login page. But it does not work beacuse I get a error telling me "localhost redirected you too many times."

Here is my middleware..

```
    public class AuthenticationCheck
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public AuthenticationCheck(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerFactory logFactory)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.User.Identity != null || !httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            httpContext.Response.Redirect("Login");
        }
        else
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
    }
}

// Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
public static class AuthenticationCheckExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseAuthenticationCheck(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<AuthenticationCheck>();
    }
}
```

What am I missing here...?

Comment: `"My question is how do I make all pages password protected except the actual login page that the users shoud be redirected to if they havent logged in yet?"` Have you used `Authorized attribute` on your controller? What did you mean by  `password protected`? without login cannot access the page right? What issue you currently having with? Can access page even without login?

Comment: Yes the pages is now accessible without me have to login before. I know that I can decorate the controller with [Authorized] but then I have to do that for every controller. Is there another way to do the same so I dont have to decorate each controller? And how do I redirect them to the login page?

Comment: Yes you have the way, you can use `Action Filter middleware`  and check the` user authentication` its convenient

Comment: You mean to create a own middleware and check if the user is authenticated, right?

Comment: Yes, right you are, if you need further assistance feel free to let me know.

Comment: Yes I added a middleware now but that one is something wrong with since I get error in browser "localhost redirected you too many times." I have updated my code above. Can you see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this goal you can use the `Authorized` attribute.

If you want to apply this rule to **all routes of your application** and don't repeat the attribute for each controller/action you have, you can define it in middleware configuration. to do that, update your **routing** like the code below

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}")
    .RequireAuthorization();
```

These enable Authorization for all of your routes.

The `RequireAuthorization` method applicable in `UseEndpoints`, `MapRazorPages`, and any other approach. after changing this, for work this mechanism you must add this code block after the `UseRouting` middleware.

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

this enables you to handle `Authentication` and your `Authorization Policies`.

after all of that, for excluding some routes (like the login page) from `Authentication` you must add `AllowAnonymous` attribute on your controller/action

Answer (score 0):

> Yes I added a middleware now but that one is something wrong with
> since I get error in browser "localhost redirected you too many
> times." I have updated my code above. Can you see what I am doing
> wrong?

Yes its quite obvious to fall into `infinite loop` because it will check the `authentication` and kept failing and keep redirecting. I am wondering you are so closed and the scenario was out of the box which is not common case and other contributor doesn't understand your requirement at all. Our plan was to not using `Authorize attribute` hence, will restrict the user and finally redirect to login page.

**Solution:**

**Middleware Class:**

```
public class ReverseAuthMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        public ReverseAuthMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
           //bool isAuthorized = true;
           var isAuthorized = httpContext.User.Claims.Any(c => c.Type != null && c.Value != null);
           
           
            if (!isAuthorized && httpContext.Request.Path.Value != "/Login/Index")
            {
                httpContext.Response.Redirect("/Login/Index");
            }

            //If the user authenticated and the Path not login then we can Move forward into the pipeline
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
    }
```

**Note:** Let's explain the scenario, we have to consider two scenario, user has to login to access any page.Thus, either he can access login page in case of `unauthorized user` or can access any page once `authenticated`. Therefore, we need to check both `authentication` and `which page he is trying to access` other than, we will be into `forever loop`. In addtion. I am checking `httpContext.User.Claims` however, yours `httpContext.User.Identity` also fine.

**Program.cs:**

```
app.UseMiddleware<ReverseAuthMiddleware>();
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I suggest you to use `Authorize` attribute hence, you were relactant to use it, therefore, I have investigated further and found this solution for you, not sure why then accept other answer.

Comment: Hello, don't take this the wrong way. I'm new to this and was not sure of the right way to choose and didn't know better. Also I really appreciate the effort you put in to this. I would like to try your suggestion also. Should I place app.UseMiddleware<ReverseAuthMiddleware>(); between app.UseAuthentication(); and app.UseAuthorization(); or should one of them not be used in this case?

Comment: Just place this  `app.UseMiddleware<ReverseAuthMiddleware>();` after the `app.UseAuthorization();` that will work accordingly. In between also alright.

Comment: Ok, but if I have this order. app.UseAuthentication, app.UseAuthorization, app.UseMiddleware<ReverseAuthMiddleware>();, app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}").RequireAuthorization(); I get redirected to the login page, but even after I login successfully httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is never true in the check in the middleware?

Comment: You are doing mess now, either use `Authorized` atrribute where you want user to `login` or use `ReverseAuthMiddleware` so that if `user not login` then cannot access other pages. But do not use both.  If you don't want to implement  `Authorized attribute` in every controller then `ReverseAuthMiddleware` this is the solution. Don't mixed both. Hope it guided you.

Comment: Yes its a mess now ;). If I have app.UseAuthorization() and then app.UseMiddleware<ReverseAuthMiddleware>(); and remove all Authorized I get redirected to the login page on my initial request. But after submitting my login information on the login page I am redirected back to the login page agan.. So I must miss something here...

Comment: Either follow my sample or follow other one, as said earlier.

Comment: Can you please show me your program.cs?

Comment: When using Identity I need to have app.UseAuthentication, maybe its why you solution works and not for me when I use Identity.....